# smooth function $\mu:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\!\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(0)>\varepsilon$, $\:\mu_{[2\varepsilon,\infty)}=0$, $\:-1<\mu'\leq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-topology

How can I prove (preferrably without the use of any heavy theorems) the existence of a smooth function $\mu\!:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\!\mathbb{R}$ with properties $\mu(0)\!>\!\varepsilon$, $\:\mu_{[2\varepsilon,\infty)}\!=\!0$, $\:-1\!<\!\mu'\!\leq\!0$?

I'm guessing [bump functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) should come in handy, but I don't know how to bound the derivative.

This is needed in the proof of Morse handle attachment theorem: Banyaga & Hurtubise, [p.65](http://books.google.si/books?id=AX-_sbMjOK4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=horizontally%20lined%20area&f=false).

Comment: You should modify a smooth cutoff function: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac 1 {\sqrt x}}&x>0\\0&x\le 0\end{cases}$$
is smooth. Note that for $x>0$ we have $f'(x) = \frac12 x^{-\frac32}e^{-\frac1{\sqrt x}}$ and $f''(x) = \frac14x^{-3}(1-3\sqrt x) e^{-\frac1{\sqrt x}}$. Therefore $0\le f'(x)\le f'(\frac19)= \frac{27}{2e^3}$.

Now set $\mu(x) = a\cdot f(b\cdot(2\epsilon - x))$ with $a=\frac76e^3\epsilon>0$ and $b=\frac1{18\epsilon}>0$. We obtain

- $\mu(x)=0$ for $x\ge 2\epsilon$
- $\mu'(x)= -a b f'(b\cdot(2\epsilon - x))$ is $\le 0 $ and $\ge -ab\cdot  \frac{27}{2e^3} = -\frac78>-1$.
- $\mu(0)=a f(2b\epsilon) = \frac76e^3\epsilon f(\frac19)=\frac76\epsilon>\epsilon$

Comment: @Eitzen: In general, for any $a\!>\!0$ and $r\!\in\!\mathbb{N}_0$, we have $$\lim_{x\downarrow0}\, (e^{-1/x^a})^{(r)}=0,$$ where $(r)$ is the $r$-th derivative, correct? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, the reason is that (e.g. by induction) the derivatives are of the form $P_r(x^{-1},x^{-1-\alpha})e^{-1/x^\alpha}$ with a polynomial $P_r(X,Y)$ and the exponential is stronger than any polynomial